# Отцентрировать блоки на Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как отцентрировать блоки на Bootstrap. 3 блока надо отцентрировать.

[image]

Comment: Приведите вашу HTML разметку.

Answer (score 1):

В Bootstrap используется сетка из 12 ячеек для выравнивая по горизонтали. 
В след примере я отсутпил 3 ячейки слева спомощью класса `col-xs-offset-3`, отвел под содержимое еще 6 `col-xs-6`. И оставил три ячейки справа. 
Выравнивание самого содежимого с помощью `text-center`

Подробнее про разметку читаейте [тут](http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid)

```css
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
.blue{
   background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container red">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center green">Меню</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  text-center blue">Контент</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3  text-center green">Футер</div>
  </div>
</div>
```